# Unable to retireve the ids of the Selected rows in Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am unable to retireve the ids of the Selected rows in Jgrid....

I have a jgrid

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    ....................
});
```

I have a button in the same jsp page

```
<input type ="button" name="button" id="button" value="OK">
```

Once I click on the button, I should be able to retrieve all the selected rows from the above grid. 
Here is my function,

```
jQuery("#button").click(function ()
var select = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) //iterate through array of selected rows
{
    alert("inside the loop");

    var id = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getRowData', select[i]);

    var selectedID = id.Emp_ID;
});
```

I am not able to retieve the ids.
Please help

Please find the full code here

```
         function load()
        {

            jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
                url:'Emp?action=getData',
                datatype: "xml",
                height: 250,
                width:900,

                colNames:
                    ['srNo','Emp_ID','NAME','ADDRESS'],   

                colModel:[
                         {name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:35,sortable:true},

                         {name:'Emp_ID',index:'Emp_ID', width:20,sortable:true,editable:true},
                         {name:'NAME',index:'NAME', width:35,sortable:false,editable:true},
                         {name:'ADDRESS',index:'ADDRESS', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true},

                          ],

                paging: true,
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                pager: $("#page"),
                sortname: 'srNo',
                loadonce:true,
                multiselect:true,
             gridComplete: function() {
                var actualrows = $("#grid").getGridParam("reccount");
                document.getElementById("rows").value = actualrows;
            }

            }).navGrid
           ('#page',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,view:true,search: true},
    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true,width:500,editurl: '', closeOnSubmit: true},
    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true,width:500,url: '', closeOnSubmit: true},
    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true,width:500,url: '',                      closeOnSubmit: true},
                {multipleSearch:true,overlay:false}

      );

        }

    jQuery("#button").click(function ()
    {
var select = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) //iterate through array of selected rows
{
 alert("inside the loop");

 var id = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getRowData', select[i]);

 var selectedID = id.Emp_ID;
     }
});

 </script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">

  <table id="grid" border="1"></table>
        <div id="page"></div>

         <input type ="hidden" name = "hidden" id ="hidden">

        <input type="hidden" id = "rows" name="actualrows" />

            <table align ="center">
            <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td><input type ="text" name="regdate" id ="regdate"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type ="button" class ="button" name="button" id="button" value="OK"></td></tr>

        </table>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Following is the test data that i have included in my grid

### srNo    Emp_ID    NAME    ADDRESS

1        Emp1     Andrew    addr

2        Emp2     Cyrus     addr

3        Emp3     Tom       addr

This is the Servlet which fills the grid

```
    if (request.getParameter("action").equals("getData")) 
   {
   try
     {
       String query="Select * from Employee";

      /* Connection code goes here*/

     pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);


    /* pagination code goes here*/

    out.print("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n");
    out.print("<rows>");
    out.print("<page>" + page + "</page>");
    out.print("<total>" + totalPages + "</total>");
    out.print("<records>" + count + "</records>");


   while(rs.next())
   {
    out.print("<row id='" + srNo + "'>");
    out.print("<cell>" + srNo + "</cell>");
    out.print("<cell>" +rs.getString(1) + "</cell>");
    out.print("<cell>"+rs.getString(2) +"</cell>");
    out.print("<cell>"+rs.getString(3) +"</cell>");
    out.print("</row>");
    srNo++;

}     
                    out.print("</rows>");
  }
 catch(Exception e)
           {

           }
  }
```

Please find the XML response...below..

```
 <body onload="fillGrid();">

 <div class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="gbox_grid" style="width: 900px;"><div class="ui-widget-overlay jqgrid-overlay" id="lui_grid"></div><div class="loading ui-state-default ui-state-active" id="load_grid" style="display: none;">Loading...</div><div class="ui-jqgrid-view" id="gview_grid" style="width: 900px;"><div class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix" style="display: none;"><a role="link" href="javascript:void(0)" class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close HeaderButton"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span></a><span class="ui-jqgrid-title"></span></div><div style="width: 900px;" class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv"><div class="ui-jqgrid-hbox"><table class="ui-jqgrid-htable" style="width:882px" role="grid" aria-labelledby="gbox_grid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><thead><tr class="ui-jqgrid-labels" role="rowheader"><th role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column" style="width: 25px;"><div id="jqgh_cb"><input id="cb_jqg" class="cbox" type="checkbox"><span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></span></div></th><th role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column" style="width: 157px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_srNo" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">srNo<span class="s-ico" style=""><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></span></div></th><th role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column" style="width: 90px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_Emp_ID" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">Emp_ID<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></span></div></th><th role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column" style="width: 157px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_NAME" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">NAME<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></span></div></th><th role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column" style="width: 453px;"><span class="ui-jqgrid-resize">&nbsp;</span><div id="jqgh_ADDRESS" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">ADDRESS<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></span></div></th></tr></thead></table></div></div><div class="ui-jqgrid-bdiv" style="height: 250px; width: 900px;"><table id="grid" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-labelledby="gbox_grid" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" style="width: 882px;"><tbody><tr id="1" role="row" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow  ui-state-highlight" aria-selected="true"><td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;width: 25px;"><input type="checkbox" id="jqg_1" class="cbox" name="jqg_1" checked="checked"></td><td role="gridcell" style="width: 157px;" title="1">1</td><td role="gridcell" style="width: 90px;" title="Emp1">Emp1</td><td role="gridcell" style="width: 157px;" title="Andrew">Andrew</td><td role="gridcell" style="width: 453px;" title="addr">addr</td></tr><tr id="2" role="row" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-state-highlight" aria-selected="true"><td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="jqg_2" class="cbox" name="jqg_2" checked="checked"></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="2">2</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Emp2">Emp2</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Cyrus">Cyrus</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="addr">addr</td></tr><tr id="3" role="row" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow"><td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="jqg_3" class="cbox" name="jqg_3"></td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="3">3</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Emp3">Emp3</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="Tom">Tom</td><td role="gridcell" style="" title="addr">addr</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="ui-jqgrid-resize-mark" id="rs_mgrid">&nbsp;</div><div id="page" style="width: 900px;" class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-pager corner-bottom"><div id="pg_page" class="ui-pager-control" role="group"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ui-pg-table" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;" role="row"><tbody><tr><td id="page_left" align="left"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ui-pg-table navtable" style="float:left;table-layout:auto;"><tbody><tr><td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Add new row" id="add_grid"><div class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span></div></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Edit selected row" id="edit_grid"><div class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span></div></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="View selected row" id="view_grid"><div class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></div></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Delete selected row" id="del_grid"><div class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></div></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-state-disabled" style="width:4px;"><span class="ui-separator"></span></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Find records" id="search_grid"><div class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span></div></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Reload Grid" id="refresh_grid"><div class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh"></span></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td id="page_center" align="center" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 278px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout:auto;" class="ui-pg-table"><tbody><tr><td id="first" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-first"></span></td><td id="prev" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-prev"></span></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-state-disabled" style="width:4px;"><span class="ui-separator"></span></td><td>Page <input class="ui-pg-input" type="text" size="2" maxlength="7" value="0" role="textbox"> of <span id="sp_1">1</span></td><td class="ui-pg-button ui-state-disabled" style="width:4px;"><span class="ui-separator"></span></td><td id="next" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" style="cursor: default;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next"></span></td><td id="last" class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-seek-end"></span></td><td><select class="ui-pg-selbox" role="listbox"><option role="option" value="10" selected="">10</option><option role="option" value="20">20</option><option role="option" value="30">30</option></select></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td id="page_right" align="right"></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>


     <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden">

    <input type="hidden" id="rows" name="actualrows" value="3">

        <table align="center">
        <tbody><tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="regdate" id="regdate"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="button" class="button" name="button" id="button" value="OK"></td></tr>

    </tbody></table>
```

WarningPlease, select row

Comment: You're missing the braces around the body of the click handler function. Is that just a problem in the question, or in the real code?

Comment: You should include more full JavaScript code which you use. Is `Emp_ID` is really the value of `name` property in some column of `colModel`? How you fill the grid? Which format of input data you use? Is `Emp_ID` could be interpreted as the **real** id of the rows in the grid? Are `Emp_ID` unique? Why you don't use the values as the rowids? In the case `jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow")` will get you all you need.

Comment: @Barmar I have included the braces around the body in the real code...

Comment: Please fix your question and show the actual code.

Comment: @Oleg Datatype i use in jgrid is "xml" Emp_ID is unique for each row. Yes..Emp_ID name exists in the ColModel. I also have srNo for each row that is unique apart from the Emp_ID.

Comment: @vani: It's better to include the code which create jqGrid.

Comment: @vani: Could you include test XML data which you use to fill the grid (two rows of data will be enough)?

Comment: @vani: It's important no know not the testdata which you posted, but the **exact XML data** which you use.

Comment: @Oleg: Currently I am working on this test data only....

Comment: @vani: Could you append your question with XML data which you use?

Comment: @Oleg: I have edited my question with the required details...

Comment: @vani: Sorry, but I asked you multiple times for **exact XML data** and not for the code which produce the data. You can for example use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Network tab of Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press F12 to start) or Google Chrome to catch HTTP traffic. Inside of HTTP response you will see the server response. The body of the response contains exact XML data.

Comment: @Oleg... I have pasted the XML data....

Comment: At last....I have got it.....I have replaced few css files and js files with the new ones..Thanks everyone for your time and help.....

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you just don't filled `id` in XML input which you used for jqGrid.

If contains of `Emp_ID` column is unique for each row then you can just include `key: true` property in the column definition (in `colModel`). In the case jqGrid will use `Emp_ID` values as `id` of rows (as rowid) and the array returned by `jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");` will get you already all what you need.

Comment: In the Column Model, I have included key:true property. Now how do I access the value.....

Comment: @vani: As I wrote `jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow")` returns the array of `Emp_ID` values of selected items.

Comment: I am not able to retrieve the selected values even after including key:true property. Please help